# Cannot find symbol symbol: method process(WorkerAnt)

Tags: java, gridworld

I am doing this AntFarm project for my Java class.  This project consists of different classes(Food, WorkerAnt, Queen) and they interact with each other using a interface(with a method called process).

http://ljhs.sandi.net/faculty/volger/apajava/GridWorld/Assignments/AntFarm/ - project

I'm currently stuck on the `processActors()` method in `WorkerAnt`. (It's almost at the bottom of the page.)

The current code is the following:

```
public void processActors(ArrayList<Actor> actors) {
  for (Actor nextActor : actors) {
    nextActor.process(this); 
  }
}
```

The error I get is the following.

> Cannot find symbol symbol: method process(WorkerAnt)

Comment: Please pick a better title. Eg, "Cannot find symbol symbol issue with AntFarm (homework) project".

Comment: Does the Actor class contain a process() method?

Comment: Also, does the method process(WorkerAnt) exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the linked assignment, `Actor` does not have a `process(WorkerAnt)` method.

Instead, this is part of the `Processable` interface (and thus `Food`).

As such, make sure your `Actor` is an `Actor` implementing `Processable` (for example a `Food`).

Ideally you'd change your `processActors(ArrayList<Actor> actors)` method to be something like `processProcessables(ArrayList<Processable> processables)`.

However, I see in the assignment that you are required to implement a `processActors(ArrayList<Actor> actors)` so you can't really do this (although I'm going to call this out as bad design - it's akin to having a method `divide(object, object)` instead of `divide(double, double)`).

To see why it is bad design, the assignment says

> processActors: Each actor in actors needs to call its process method.

Except `Actor`s don't have `process` methods - `Processable`s do, and `Actor`s are not `Processable`.

In any case, you will have to settle for the fact that you expect some `Actor`s to be `Processable`s and do something like this:

```
for(Actor nextActor : actors)
{
    if (nextActor instanceof Processable)
        ((Processable)nextActor).process(this); 
}
```

However, you should have realised this from the assignment:

> An Actor could be a QueenAnt, a Cake,
>   a Cookie, or a WorkerAnt. Without the
>   Processable interface, processActors
>   would need to determine the type of
>   actor and then downcast the actor
>   reference before making the call to
>   process. But, since each of these
>   classes implements Processable,
>   processActors only needs to cast the
>   actor to Processable before the call.
>   This polymorphic processing is allowed
>   because Processable contains the
>   process abstract method. The Java Run
>   Time Environment (JRE) determines the
>   actual type of object at runtime and
>   calls the appropriate process method.